# Xcode keeps returning "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value", when attempting to add an impulse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am trying to add an impulse to the ball reffered to in the code, but xcode keeps returning "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

```
class GameScene: SKScene {

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    super.didMoveToView(view)
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    borderBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = borderBody
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
    let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as SKSpriteNode
    ball.physicsBody!.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, -10))

}

}
```

Comment: You're force unwrapping ball.physicsBody, that's most likely nil and triggering the fatal error.

Comment: how would I fix it though?

Comment: If it's nil, you'll have to live with that and survive it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is really late, but I have a real solution! You were most likely using [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/84341/create-breakout-game-sprite-kit-swift) tutorial, I'm assuming. I came across this question while also searching for the same issue.

So XCode is throwing this error because the ball you're referencing is nil. The reason for that is because this line:

```
let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as SKSpriteNode
```

is referencing a sprite from the .sks file by the name of `BallCategoryName` or `"ball"`. FUNNY THING IS: The tutorial never told us to set a name. So, it can't find the sprite named `"ball"`. Simply go back and name that ball sprite as `ball` and your code will work!!

Comment: No problem. I fought with that tutorial for a few hours. I figured the least I could do was ease someone else's frustration! :)

Comment: Not your mistake! The guy writing the tutorial made the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues with optionals in your code. I'm surprised it compiles, as you are essentially casting an optional to a non-optional type:

```
let ball = childNodeWithName(BallCategoryName) as SKSpriteNode
// childNodeWithName return type is 'SKNode?', not 'SKNode'
// also why the cast in the first place? physicsBody is a property of SKNode, no need for the downcast.
```

Further down, you force unwrap ball.physicsBody, which constitutes a deadly swift cardinal sin. When dealing with optionals, you can check for nil:

```
let myOptional = funcWhichReturnsOptional()
if( myOptional != nil )
{
    //we're 100% sure we have a value
    let myVal = myOptional!
}
else
{
    //Handle nil
}
```

or use optional binding( most idiomatic ):

```
if let myValue = funcWhichReturnsOptional()
{
    // 'if let' pattern means you directly get the unwrapped value,
    // if non nil of course.
}
else
{
    //Handle nil
}
```

or optional chaining( useful when you don't need to handle nil case ):

```
let myOptional = funcWhichReturnsOptional()
myOptional?.foo() //foo is invoked only if myOptional is non nil
```

One absolute rule: NEVER force unwrap an optional if you are not 100% sure it contains value.

To summarize, something in your code is nil and you are not properly handling that case. Could be your cast when calling childNodeWithName, or ball.physicsBody which is nil. Apply proper patterns, and you'll be fine.